# scroll to next element with scrollTop for a survey - JQuery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, survey

I'm creating a small dynamic survey, with radio buttons, and I am trying to scroll to the next question when one question is answered.

The survey is built like this (basic survey)

```
<section class='question'>
    <h2>Title of the question</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" class='choice'>Answer 1</li>
        <li><input type="radio" class='choice'>Answer 2</li>
        <li><input type="radio" class='choice'>Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The script for the animation is below

```
<script>
$(".choice").click(function() {
var next;
next = $(this).parent().next().find(".choice");
$("html, body").delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: next.offset().top}, 2000);
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly well when Answer 1 or 2 are selected, but it doesn't work for Answer 3.
The console says "next" is undefined.

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why are you scrolling though answers? Wasn't it suppose to scroll through your questions?

Comment: $(this).parent().next().find(".choice"); get the next inout choice : there are none after 3rd : undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have a multiple questions with radio answers and when you click a radio input you need to scroll to the next question. In this case you can watch for on change events on the radio buttons. When you get a on change event you get the container of the answer and then use `.next()` to get the next question. If there is next question you scroll to it with a nice animation transition.

**JS:**

```
$('.choice').on('change', function() {
    var nextQuestion = $(this).closest('.question').next();

    if (nextQuestion.length !== 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: nextQuestion.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzda8e57/

Comment: Thank you very much
That does the job, even though I still don't know why my previous code did not work for the last answer of each question.
I wish I could upvote for your answer, but since I'm new here, I have to wait for 15 upvotes to have the right to upvote myself...